# Vanilla bridges work fine in Tor Browser (Windows) and Orbot (Android) but doesn't anywhere else

Tags: configuration, bridge, linux, debian

Vanilla bridges do not work in OnionFruit vpn-style program for Windows, and on my Debian system - tor service won't start also.

In Debian 10 I've added these lines at the end of /etc/tor/torrc file:

```
UseBridges 1
bridge 23.22.110.133:443 A127C4FDAD3080541EC6ACC0D8ACD704
bridge 24.22.1.54:443 ABCDEFGHAD3080541EC6ACC0D8ACD704
```

Then I run `sudo service tor restart`
And to see results `sudo journalctl -exft Tor`

It just stops at

```
Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus
```

As I said bridges are fine and working ones.
How to make bridges work in Debian?

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked after clearing cache

```
sudo su
cd /var/lib/tor
rm *
```

and rebooting afterwards